# The launch page generated by flutter_native_splash is not full screen on android 13 ,but it works normally on android 11

Tags: flutter

The launch page generated by flutter_native_splash is not full screen on android 13 ,but it works normally on android 11

wrong one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRxvB.jpg)
normal one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEISw.png)

followed is my config

```yaml
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/images/start.png
  android: true
  ios: true
  fullscreen: true
  android_12:
    image: assets/images/start.png
    icon_background_color: "#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: Android 12 introduce some [limitations](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#dimensions) to splash screens